# UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification is deprecated, any alternative?

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, xcode11, ios13

I have changed my app target to IOS 13 to check the deprecated methods in my app and I am getting below warning:

> 'UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - Use viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: instead.
>   Here is the code which I have implemented in my project.

```
    - (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(onChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification:)
                                                     name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Please suggest me the solution for ios 12 and ios 13.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Implement `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` and do whatever you where doing in `onChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification:` there?

Comment: Could you give me a small demo?

Comment: `- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator { [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator]; [self onChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification:nil]; }`?

Answer (score 5):

Though this is an old post, I also faced this situation recently. Just implement the protocol  `UIContentContainer`

```
@interface MyViewController : NSObject <UIContentContainer>
```

And implement the method in the implementation and within the method add call your function.

```
@implementation MyViewController {
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
        [self onChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification];
    }
@end
```

### Swift

```swift
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    
    // Put code to be run BEFORE the rotation here... 

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
        // Put code to be run after the rotation,
        // or after frame-size change here...
    }
}
```

Some other useful checks:

```
if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
    print("Landscape")
}
if UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat {
    print("Flat")
} else {
    print("Portrait")
}
```

Comment: What if it's not a view or a view without controller? Also, `viewWillTransitionToSize` is only called if the controller is added with `addChild` to another controller (and adding just controller's view is not enugh). **Refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69095480/8740349)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```objectivec
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
    selector: @selector(onChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification:)
    name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
    object: nil];
```

But note that it just works and I never call below:

```objectivec
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

So, maybe it's enabled by default.

### Swift 5

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
    selector: #selector(onLayoutChange),
    name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification,
    object: nil)

// ...

@objc public func onLayoutChange() {
    // Handle change here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and here is what worked for me:

In my UIViewController I had to override the viewWillTransition function and voila.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to:size, with: coordinator)
    let before = self.view.window?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
        let after = self.view.window?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation
        if before != after {
            // rotation detected, call you rotation handler here
        }
    }
```

}

Source: https://www.biteinteractive.com/dealing-with-ios-13-deprecations/

Mahmud Ahsan's answer is good just that is missing the detection code.

Comment: Maybe the "`if before != after`" part is not required, because the callback will be called each time (and **not** just once after the user stopped rotating the device).

Comment: Well in my case I needed it because I want to get notified only when I have a change of orientation... I guess from here everybody can make their mind what to do next