# How to implement viewWillAppear() instead of deprecated didChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification in this case?

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, screen-orientation, viewwilltransitiontosize

I would like to ask how shall I shall use viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: instead of deprecated 'didChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification'. Even though in Xcode https://github.com/Mairoslav/8.2.MeMe.2.0.rev it seems that all works well except of this warning I am curious how to silence this warning or make use of it.

I want that when orientation changes from portrait to landscape and back and forth the constraints do adjust accordingly as done via method @objc func orientationChanged.

Still this warning in question is within the Notification where method @objc func orientationChanged is called.

I tried to silence it via using nil for name: , however with nil for name there is an error.

The code in question:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.orientationChanged), name: UIApplication.didChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification, object: nil)
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification is deprecated, any alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56900491/uiapplicationdidchangestatusbarorientationnotification-is-deprecated-any-altern), particularly this answer may be of use https://stackoverflow.com/a/69095480/5508175

Comment: Hi @Andrew I received also the answer that "If you want to use the method with the notification just ignore the warning". I try to study further options, thank you for hint.